# How to make a web link in android clickable twice a day in android

Tags: android, onclick

I have a business directory in which web link of different business is given. All the details of business listing is getting fetched through a web service. When a user clicks on any link he/she gets one credit or score. There are multiple web links as it is business directory.As rewards are there for certain points, users can misuse this to get extra points  so i want to keep that link clickable but points gets aded to his/her account only twice a day that is once after 12 hours.For example if a user click on a link at 12:00 pm than 1 point will be added in his/her account and next point will be added for the same link onclick at 12:00 am but at the same time rest of the links should be working and points should be getting added in his/her account if that is the first time he/she is clicking it.For example there are links:-

1. www.abc.com
2. www.xyz.com

If i click on link 1 at 12:00 am than point gets added in my account and next time point will be added at 12:00 pm if i click on this link again.
After clicking on link 1 i if i click on link 2 the same process should continue.
How can i do this?

Below attached is the code for the activity on which business details along with weblinks  are getting fetched:-

public class BussinessDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity{

```
LinearLayout layMap, layWeb, layDes;
TextView tvMap, tvWeb, tvDes;
ImageView imgIcon;
SponcerDetailsModel model;
public static boolean isAdd = false;
private AppPreferences mPreferences;
ImageButton iBtnBack;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.business_details);

    imgIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_bussiness);
    iBtnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtn_back);
    layMap = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_map);
    layWeb = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lay_web);

    tvMap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_map);
    tvWeb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_web);
    tvDes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_description);

    mPreferences = new AppPreferences(this);
    isAdd = false;

    model = (SponcerDetailsModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("OBJ");

    iBtnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    tvMap.setText(model.getAddress());


    tvDes.setText(model.getDescription());
    tvWeb.setText(model.getWebsite());

    Glide.with(this).load(model.getImage()).centerCrop().into(imgIcon);

    layMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+ model.getMap_link());
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    layWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(model.getWebsite() != null && !model.getWebsite().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BussinessDetailsActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Thanks for supporting our Sponsors")
                        .setTitle("Alert")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                String url = model.getWebsite();
                                if(!url.contains("http://")){
                                    url = "http://"+url;
                                }
                                isAdd = true;
                                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(BussinessDetailsActivity.this, "Website is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(isAdd){
        isAdd = false;
        new addpoints()
                .execute(UtilConnection.Rewards_webservices
                        + "pointsadd.php?");
    }
}

public class addpoints extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String points, msg;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (ConnectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet(BussinessDetailsActivity.this)) {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BussinessDetailsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        } else {
            UtilConnection.dialog(BussinessDetailsActivity.this, "" + ConnectionDetector.NETWORK_MESSAGE);
            cancel(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            ServiceHandler handler = new ServiceHandler();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_user", URLEncoder
                    .encode(mPreferences.getStringPreference(AppPreferences.USER_ID))));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("points", URLEncoder.encode("1")));

            String str = handler.makeServiceCall(urls[0],
                    ServiceHandler.POST, nameValuePairs);
            System.err.println("" + str);
            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(str);
            msg = jsono.getString("msg");
            points = jsono.getString("points");
            Log.e("point=",points);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pDialog.cancel();
        if (points != null) {
            UtilConnection.dialog(BussinessDetailsActivity.this, "Congratulations, you have earned credits");
            mPreferences.setStringPreference(AppPreferences.USER_POINTS, points);
        } else {
            UtilConnection.dialog(BussinessDetailsActivity.this, "" + msg);
        }

    }
}
```

}

And my xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e8e8e8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibtn_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_backspace" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_48"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_bussiness"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lay_web"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_website"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_public_black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_web"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                        android:background="@color/gray" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lay_map"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_map"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_map"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                        android:background="@color/gray" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_des"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_description" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                        android:background="@color/gray" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can save the date and time in shared preferences or in local database once the user has clicked on the link, and from the second time he clicks just check the date and time condition and proceeds with the point if it's above 12 hours,
If you post your code here that would be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: You should make a rest service that keeps tracks of the link clicked per UID along with time and update the `link_clicked` counter when current time > `last_updated_time` + 43200000 ms.